# What's going on in Charlotte Riddell's Old House in Vauxhall Walk?

Tags: short-stories, charlotte-riddell

Maybe I'm looking too hard for meanings that aren't there, but can someone explain to me what's going on in Charlotte Riddell's Old House in Vauxhall Walk?
How was the second burglar caught?
What was up with the rattle?
How did the mirror get broken?
What story did William tell Graham that he never knew before?
I feel these questions mean I just didn't get the whole thing, so I'd appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rattle is probably a police rattle:

> The origin of the rattle is not clear, but what has come to be known as the "Victorian Police Rattle" came into use sometime in the late seventeenth or early eighteenth century when night watchmen and/or village constables began using them to "raise the alarm". They proved to be an ideal method to summon aid, sound the fire alarm, or, just generally get folks attention. A traditional rattle was constructed of wood, usually oak, where one or two blades are held in a frame and a ratchet turned – generally by swinging – to make the blades 'snap' thus creating a very loud noise. - [Saint Paul Police Historical Society](http://www.spphs.com/history/whistles/index.php)

The rattle alerted the police who were able to catch the burglars/murderers.

It is not clear exactly how the mirror was broken, but it happens after the two men with the knife were apprehended. If we make some assumptions, it might be that they were the ones who murdered the old lady. Justice is served and her ghost is laid to rest. The mirror is broken to reveal the treasure, either by the ghost herself, as an act of gratitude, or by some other kind of supernatural karmic force, to reward the young man who solved the mystery of her murder.

As for the story William told Graham, I think this part of the story is deliberately left vague. I'm guessing it was to do with the history of his parents' relationship. William says that although Graham thinks he hated her, Graham's father was *'was over fond of your [Graham's] mother'* and we also know that his father thought Graham resembled his mother *'in mind as well as body'*. My interpretation is that the father was hurt by something the mother did (e.g. maybe she had an affair, or ran off with someone) and sometimes takes it out on the son that resembles her. Hearing the details of the story gives Graham a better understanding of his father and inspires him to improve their relationship. Graham is also buoyed by his recent success, which helps him to confidently approach his father.

([Link to the story](http://www.searchengine.org.uk/ebooks/102/77.pdf))

Comment: Welcome to Literature! Thanks for this nice first post :-)

Comment: When Graham saw the candle the night before, was it the burglars already searching the house? So he understood what was going on? Thanks for such a nice reply, I didn't think I would get any! I think the rattle link is broken, tho.

Comment: @entonio I fixed the rattle link.